# How can I optimize this join on timestamps in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL version 10

Windows 10

16GB RAM

SSD

I'm ashamed to admit that, despite searching the hundred years of PG support archives, I cannot figure out this most basic problem. But here it is...

I have big_table with 45 million rows and little_table with 12,000 rows. I need to do a left join to include all big_table rows, along with the id's of little_table rows where big_table's timestamp overlaps with two timestamps in little_table.

This doesn't seem like it should be an extreme operation for PG, but it is taking 2 1/2 hours!

Any ideas on what I can do here? Or do you think I have unwittingly come up against the limitations of my software/hardware combo given the table size?

Thanks!

### little_table with 12,000 rows

```
CREATE TABLE public.little_table
(
    id bigint,
    start_time timestamp without time zone,
    stop_time timestamp without time zone
);


CREATE INDEX idx_little_table
    ON public.little_table USING btree
    (start_time, stop_time DESC);
```

### big_table with 45 million rows

```
CREATE TABLE public.big_table
(
    id bigint,
    datetime timestamp without time zone
) ;

CREATE INDEX idx_big_table
    ON public.big_table USING btree
    (datetime);
```

### Query

```
explain analyze
select
  bt.id as bt_id,
  lt.id as lt_id
from
    big_table bt
left join
  little_table lt
on
    (bt.datetime between lt.start_time and  lt.stop_time)
```

### Explain Results

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.29..3260589190.64 rows=64945831346 width=16) (actual time=0.672..9163998.367 rows=1374445323 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on big_table bt  (cost=0.00..694755.92 rows=45097792 width=16) (actual time=0.014..10085.746 rows=45098790 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using idx_little_table on little_table lt  (cost=0.29..57.89 rows=1440 width=24) (actual time=0.188..0.199 rows=30 loops=45098790)
        Index Cond: ((bt.datetime >= start_time) AND (bt.datetime <= stop_time))
Planning time: 0.165 ms
Execution time: 9199473.052 ms
```

NOTE: My actual query criteria is a bit more complex, but this seems to be the root of the problem. If I can fix this part, I think I can fix the rest.

Comment: The biggest contributor to the runtime is the Seq Scan on big_table, but as you want all rows from that table, there is nothing to avoid that. And the result of that join returns  1.3 **billion** rows. Which means on average there are 30 rows in little_table matching one row in big_table. But what are you doing with a result like that? What are you planning to do with 1.3 billion rows? You can probably only improve that by getting faster hardware. Although I am a bit surprised that Postgres didn't choose an Parallel Seq Scan for such a big table. Did you turn off parallel query?

Comment: I am actually creating a new table from the results. The real query is "create table as select..." and there will be a maximum of one little_table row per big_table row. So the output table will always have same number of rows as big_table. Of course, there's no way for PG to know that at query time, but in reality that's what I'm after. 
I have not turned off any anything. In other versions of my query, I did see parallel seq scan, but it didn't seem to run fast either (although I rarely wait 2 hours for it to finish to know for sure).

Comment: Your query clearly shows that each row in big_table is matched multiple times, not just once. If you do expect only one match, then you should investigate your data.

Comment: You're right. In my zeal to simplify the query for this post, I left some important filters out. Dang. I'll fix it up it up and come back. I predict it will be faster but still unbearably slow... which is where I started. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating 1.3 billion rows seems pretty extreme to me.  How often do you need to do this, and how fast do you need it to be?

To explain a bit about your current plan:

> ```
> Index Cond: ((bt.datetime >= start_time) AND (bt.datetime <= stop_time))
> ```

While it is not obvious from what is displayed above, this always scans about half the index.  It starts at the beginning of the index, and stops once `start_time > bt.datetime`, using `bt.datetime <= stop_time` as an in-index filter that need to examine each row before rejecting it.

To flesh out Bergi's answer, you could do this:

```
alter table little_table add range tsrange;
update little_table set range =tsrange(start_time,stop_time,'[]');
create index on little_table using gist(range);

select
  bt.id as bt_id,
  lt.id as lt_id
from
    big_table bt
left join
  little_table lt
on
    (bt.datetime <@ lt.range)
```

In my hands, that is about 4 times faster than your current method.

If your join did not need to do a left join, then you could get some more efficient operations by joining the tables in the opposite order.  Perhaps you could get better performance by separating this into 2 operations, and inner join and then a probe for missing values, and combining the results.

Comment: Yeah, as @a_horse_with_no_name pointed out above, I completely screwed up my example. In my real query, the number of output rows is the same as big_table. It was late, and I was trying to make a simple example.. and messed it up. Anyway, despite that, your method did help quite a bit! Although still slow, I'm seeing a significant improvement. I'm sure if I could communicate the entirety of the query, some of you guys would know how to really speed it up. I still feel like it could execute in just a few minutes. Maybe I'll try in a new question sometime. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This query cannot perform any faster.

Since there is no equality operator (`=`) in your join condition, the only strategy left to PostgreSQL is a nested loop join. 45 million repetitions of an index scan on the small table just take a while.

Comment: Could it not also do a sort-merge join?

Comment: No. By what criterion should the small table be sorted?

Comment: By `start_time` I would assume, just like the existing index? I would assume if the intervals are known to be quite small, this should be faster.

Comment: Wait. I guess the intervals having to be *known* is the crux. The index would have to store the maximum `end_time` as well, essentially becoming an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Comment: Right, and you cannot sort intervals. Anyway, only nested loop joins can be used in PostgreSQL if the join condition contains no `=` operator.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest trying to change the `start_time` and `end_time` columns in the 
little table to a single [`tsrange` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN). According to the docs, this datatype [supports a GIST index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING) which can speed up the "range contains element" operator `@>`. Maybe this will do better than the index scan on your current btree.

Comment: Thank you. This method did help quite a bit.